# How to print a variable from another .java file?

Tags: java

how can I call a variable from another java file? Every time I try to System.out.Println I receive a **null**. But it works in the original code. I want to print the name variavle in the MartianApp Class/file.

Here is the original code:

```
    import java.util.Random;

public class Martian 

{
  static String name;

  static int count;

  static Random rand = new Random();
  
         public static void main(String[] args) {
         
         Martian getRandomName = new Martian(); {
         count = count++;
         char c = (char)(rand.nextInt(26) + 'a');
         int min = 10;
         int max = 99;
  
         int num = rand.nextInt(max - min) + min;
         
         name = c + String.valueOf(num) + " /" + count;
         
         };
         
        
         
         System.out.println (name);
         }
         
};
```

Here is the second code:

```
    public class MartianApp
   {

   public static void main (String[] args)
      {
       
       System.out.println(Martian.name);
      }
      };
```

Comment: You might want to look at a tutorial on classes and instance variables. Public static variables that are modifiable are generally bad practice

Comment: You would need to make it ``public static String name`` is order to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You first have to assign a value to `name`. Run the `main` method of the `Martian` class first.

```
Martian.main(null);
System.out.println(Martian.name); // unnecessary as there is a println in Martian.main()
```

Comment: thank you! this worked, and you were right the println was unnecessary and made it print twice.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are getting null as the value for name variable is you are executing only the main method of MartianApp class.Because of that Martian class main method won't be run so the updation of value for name variable after running the main method of Martian class won't be happen.That's why you are getting the output as null.

Solution:

```
public class MartianApp
{

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
       Martian.main(null);//Now the main method of Martian class will be executed and name variable will be updated
        System.out.println(Martian.name);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace **static String name;** in  class Martian with  **static String name="John";**
Then first run class Martian
Later on run class MartianApp.
It will show the output as John

Comment: I do not want to choose the output, I want to randomly generate the name, which is why I did not put static String name ="John";

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to access a variable which is not public. The variables have certain [access scopes](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/) that define from where you can access them. In your case

```
static String name;
```

is a `default` access scope, meaning you can't use it outside of its package. You can fix this by changing it to a `public` variable like this

```
public static String name;
```

This however is NOT the way to go in Java. It would work, but it's a very bad practice. If you want to access the variables of a class, by default, you should create a getter method for them.

```
public class Martian {
    private String name;
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Then you can instantiate your `Martian.class` and call the getter for it

```
Martian martian = new Martian();
System.out.println(martian.getName());
```

Read up on how [getters and setters work](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_encapsulation.asp). You shouldn't make everything `static` if there isn't a very good reason to do so.